# Cannot connect to SQL Server via SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I can connect via Windows auth but none of the SQL Server authentication credentials work, even though they work for my coworkers on their computers. It says "Login Failed". It doesn't seem like any SQL Server authentication works for any server.  Does anyone know of settings I can look for, anything with firewalls maybe? Or something on SQL Server that could be blocking just me?

Details say

> Msg 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1, Line Number: 65536.

Comment: Under the Server Security settings in SQL Server Mangement Studio, make sure that the "Server Authentication" option is set to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".  Make sure your server firewall allows inbound TCP on port 1433 (or whatever you're using).  If you're connecting remotely ensure that you have TCP/IP protocol enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Those settings appeared to be correct. I ended up uninstalling SSMS and installed the newest 2017 SSMS version and now I can log in using SQL Server Authentication.  So never solved it with the original version.

Answer (score 1):

Login with windows, right click on the server and select "Properties".

In the Properties dialog click "Security".

In the right pane, under "Server Authentication", select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Not sure if you need to restart SQL Service or reboot the server after this.

Answer (score 0):

Following Tab Alleman Answer -
You will need to restart SQL service to activated the functionality.